# Transpose data from model objects for django-datatables-view

Tags: python, django, tableview, transpose

I have data in the following (simplified) format:

MetricData(models.Model) with following fields: id, metric, date, facility, value

Now I want to create a table with the following format (execute the script to get the indented output table):

```html
 <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Facility 1</th>
    <th>Facility 2</th>
    <th>Facility 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>03/2019</td>
    <td>1.0</td>
    <td>1.5</td>
    <td>2.5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>04/2019</td>
    <td>1.5</td>
    <td>1.5</td>
    <td>2.0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, the number of facilities which is dynamic (new ones can be added to the database), are the column headers. For each facility there will be metric data in the database.

All examples from django-datatables-view I find are basically using models directly and one model entry is converted to one table row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `QuerySet` for your model to get a list of headers:

```
class MetricDataQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    @property
    def headers(self):
        return [getattr(instance, self.model.header_column) for instance in self]
class MetricData(models.Model):
    header_column = 'facility'
    ...

    objects = MetricDataQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Notice I added the `header_column`, instead of hard coding `facility` in the `QuerySet`.  This allows you to reuse the QuerySet for different models if you end up needing to.

Now, in your view:

```
def some_view(request):
    ...
    context = {
    'objects': MetricData.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

Finally, on `some_template.html`, you can do this:

```
<table>
<tr>
{% for header in objects.headers %}
  <th>{{ header }}</th>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% for object in objects %}
<tr>
  <td>row.date</td>
  <td>row.metric</td>
  <td>row.value</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```